# Best way to integrate renv in VScode

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, renv

I am new to using VScode. Rstudio has a better integration for renv. The problem with VScode is that it depends on R packages to be well integrated with R. I tried the solution [here](https://github.com/REditorSupport/vscode-R/wiki/Working-with-renv-enabled-projects)
But for somereason. It does not work. The package is installed, but I noticed that there are issues with auto-completion and other VScode features. Is there a good way to make renv work without needing to customize all my VScode settings\keybindigs and everything for each project?